# How could I use polymorphism here to improve my code?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I've read around that instead of using `instanceof` and `getClass` methods to implement polymorphism, as it's better object-oriented practice.

If my program looks like the following:

```
Piece
SlowPiece extends Piece,
FastPiece extends Piece,
SlowFlexible extends SlowPiece,
FastFlexible extends FastPiece
```

And I have the following rule: `SlowPiece's can only move one space, and FastPiece's as many as they'd like.`

How would I use `polymorphism` to ensure that if I'm moving a Piece like `Piece piece1 = new SlowPiece();` that it is not moved more than one?

I've got a class for the game-board, and it should be able to move the piece, but I'm not sure how to stop it from moving a SlowPiece more than 1 without code-sniffing.

Basically, I get how polymorphism is fantastic for say, listing things, but with actually interacting with them I don't get how to use it properly.

Comment: I would argue that a manual dispatch is *never* showing polymorphism (of any type), but ..

Comment: In any case, why not just an `int maximumNumberOfSpaces() { .. }` method? Also, consider *interfaces* for contracts (subclassing is just an easy way to share behavior).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `Piece` abstract and add an abstract method `move()` to `Piece` (you could also user an interface). Implement `move()` differently (a `SlowPiece` only moves 1 spot, etc).

```
public abstract class Piece {
    public abstract void move();
}

public class SlowPiece extends Piece {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("moving a slow piece");
    }
}

public class FastPiece extends Piece {
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("moving a fast piece");
    }
}

Piece f = new FastPiece();
f.move();       

Piece s = new SlowPiece();
s.move();
```

Here, `move()` has all the moving logic; you could even use some overloads to allow for movement variety (like take N/S/W/E as arguments, etc).

Comment: As the piece needs to have knowledge of the board, this isn't possible unless I pass the board each time, right? I need to make sure the move won't push it off the edge of the board (so I have to check the indices of the 2D-array) and make sure no other pieces currently occupy the space it intends to move to. I heavily considered this option, but I didn't see how I could get it to move if I didn't have any knowledge of where else on the board it could move to.

Comment: You should probably make all the `Piece`s elements of a `Game` object (which, in turn, also contains a `Board` object) to allow cross-access. Again, this is just one pattern, but to me it seems intuitive.

Comment: If you don't want to use a larger object (that may grow into a God object), use dependency injection (which is another pattern).

Answer (score 3):

As another consideration to this problem, let's understand the basic overall concept.

- A `Piece` can `move()`.
- Certain types of `Piece` `move()` in a different manner than others.

One can declare `Piece` as an interface, and have all other `Piece`s implement this.  This way, you're *guaranteeing* that every `Piece` has a `move()`, and also forcing you to ensure that every `move()` is distinct, depending on the `Piece`.

Comment: Another way is to make the `Piece` an abstract class. This would be more easy if there are other common methods and prevents you to code the common ones only ones

Comment: That aspect is already well-covered in David Titarenco's answer.  It depends somewhat on what you're trying to accomplish with your objects, and how (in)specific you want to get with them.

Answer (score 1):

More than polymorphism you should probably think about responsabilities.

You "board" class should do just something like

```
piece.move();
```

and the piece should know how to move.
So if you have like a dice you can pass to the move method the number and act consequently as

```
piece.move(moves);
```

---

EDIT:

the board should manage the movements, so let the move method return an int of the steps made by the piece. The movement should be managed from another class, like board, not from the piece itself.

I suggest you a very interesting book about OO Analysis: "Applying uml and patterns" by Craig Larman. It contains also a step-by-step example of a board game as Monopoly!

Comment: As the piece needs to have knowledge of the board, this isn't possible unless I pass the board each time, right? I need to make sure the move won't push it off the edge of the board (so I have to check the indices of the 2D-array) and make sure no other pieces currently occupy the space it intends to move to.

Comment: Conceptually a piece shouldn't have the knowledge of the board because it's just a piece. Make the move method return an int to understand how many steps did and manage this information with your board. : )